# At what relative speed (slow/medium/ or fast) do electric skateboards recharge the most efficiently while going downhill?

Tags: motor, regenerative

Most electric skateboards recharge while going downhill. What would be the most efficient relative speed to go down hill?

I would argue that going slower would use less energy and recharge the battery most efficiently. But I also would argue that going too slow would be required to use energy to braking rather than create energy (maybe?).

Comment: Likely medium. At slow speed the EMF is too low to use efficiently. At high speed you lose too much energy to air resistance.

Answer (score 2):

If you go downhill, potential energy is released at a rate \$ m g \frac{dh}{dt} \$ with h being your altitude. This is the maximum amount of power available. It is proportional to slope, speed, and weight.

A significant fraction of this power is lost due to air resistance (a person on a skateboard isn't the most aerodynamic object) then to motor/generator losses and other losses. All of this depends on speed, so I can't give an exact number.

Assuming battery voltage V is constant, the maximum charging current I the battery can take determines the maximum charging power P. If the battery is almost fully charged, I will be lower, so P will be lower too.

Keeping your velocity constant using only regenerative braking is possible as long as:

1. the motor-generator is powerful enough to absorb all the available power, so none of that power goes to increase your kinetic energy (ie, speed).
2. the battery can absorb all the power produced by the motor. If it cannot, then the controller will have to reduce braking to avoid overvoltage.

So basically, if you're going downhill too fast then you'll have to use old-fashioned brakes. H fast that is depends on slope and weight, because the limit is power which is a product of the speed, slope and weight. If you're going on a flat road and simply want to slow down, then you don't have the imperative to not accelerate downhill, so regen braking will always work, but the rate at which it will slow you down depends on how much power the motor can transfer into the battery.

If you want to charge your battery with the optimum efficiency, then it would probably be better to go slow, because losses due to drag increase with velocity. But not too slow, because the motor-generator will become inefficient at low speed. There's probably an optimum value, but it will depend on slope and weight.

Answer (score 0):

Going downhill uses less energy. Faster will produce a higher voltage.

On the level going slower uses less power over a longer time for the same distance, so the reduction in energy may not be as much as you think.

Looks like it is time for experimentation.